# how to remove an object only if it exists on iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I want to remove a UILabel from the UIView dynamically. There are some branching and looping, and in the end when I remove it by 'removeFromSuperview' sdk crashes as it doesn't exist anymore, in some cases.

```
[lbl_timer removeFromSuperview];
```

So what i wanted is simply how to know if an object exists?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll really need to clarify in what sense you mean by "exists" as that can be interpreted in various ways.

<strike>You may find that an object's retainCount may satisfy your definition of exists in this case. If you aren't familiar with Objective-C's memory management, just know that once an object's retainCount reaches 0, it is deallocated and usually no longer "exists."</strike>

```
if ([lbl_timer retainCount] >= 1) {
    // The object is owned/retained by at least one thing,
    // assuming a parentview is an owner
    [lbl_timer removeFromSuperview];
} else {
    // The object isn't retained by anyone
}
```

This is honestly not the most reliable or "safe" way to check.

**EDIT:** The point has been brought up that calling retainCount on a deallocated object will cause a crash. It's probably best to avoid doing that type of check. Sticking with the method below should be much safer.

---

If you know it specifically crashes because it doesn't have a parentview you might be able to check if it even has a parentview.

```
if ([lbl_timer superview] != nil) {
    [lbl_timer removeFromSuperView];
}
```

**ADDITIONALLY:** It might even be safer to make sure lbl_timer isn't nil'd out first.

```
if (lbl_timer != nil) {
    if ([lbl_timer superview] != nil) {
        [lbl_timer removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
there was a parent view, but I wanted to know if it has already removed, it was crashing on second removal, I think. I had another global variable changing with it, I used it as a flag, cause it was urgent.
I'll look in to the memory management, and the 'nil' was a new idea for me. thanks again

Comment: Not sure if you can invoke `retainCount` for objects already deallocated, especially if the memory was reused.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'd have to test that out, but ya, that might cause a crash. It probably would be safer to test to make sure the object isn't nil'ed out first.

Comment: Sending `-retainCount` to an object that has been deallocated is almost guaranteed to crash. About the only time that `-retainCount` will ever return 0 is if it was sent to a nil object.

Answer (score 1):

If by "exists" you mean "has not been deallocated," there's no way to do that. The memory where the object was may have already been replaced with a new object. However, if the object has been deallocated, it must've already been removed from its superview, because the superview will keep a reference to it.

If you're the one who is doing the releasing, then you can set `lbl_timer` to `nil` immediately after the release, so that `-removeFromSuperview` is sent to a nil object and does nothing. If that's not possible, you should show us some code.

Comment: You should always, always ALWAYS set a value to nil after you are releasing it for the last time.  That is mostly in dealloc - make sure you set references to nil.